Typescript assign multiple custom interfaces
I have 3 interfaces where I want to assign 2 interfaces to a key of another interface
interface x{
   id: number;
   name: string;
}

interface y{
   id: number;
   roll: string;
}

interface z{
   id: number;
   user: x | y;
}

But I can have an object of type z with 3 keys
let temp: z = {
   id: 1,
   name: 'User',
   roll: '10'
}

I want ts error where it says I can assign either name or roll but not both

You need to write your own exhaustive union if you care about that. See linked q/a above and this playground link.

You could use a make-type function with overloads:
Playground
interface x{
   id: number;
   name: string;
}

interface y{
   id: number;
   roll: string;
}

function makeZ(obj: x) : x;
function makeZ(obj: y) : y;
function makeZ(obj: x | y) {
   return obj;
}

let temp = makeZ({
   id: 1,
   name: 'User',
   roll: '10'
})

